# unexpected late AppDelegate method call time on iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, appdelegate, ios11

I have built and run my app on different version of iPhone 7.
Same code was executed but [AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive] was called with delay on iOS 11 devices.

I did couple tests and the method delay is always reproducible.
On iOS 10, time elapses between `-[UIApplicationDelegate application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` and `-[UIApplicationDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:]` is around **300ms** while on iOS 11 is around **1300ms**

I hope to know what has been added to app lifecycle in iOS 11.

Comment: Have you tried using Time Profiler in Instruments? You can potentially see what's causing the slowdown. Also, did you measure on a simulator or on a device?

Comment: @MishaKarpenko I don't see anything indicating the call time of method using Time Profiler. But I got the result by logging the current time which should be reliable I guess..   And yes, I was using same devices (iPhone 7)

Comment: @JayceeJiang Are you prompting your user for any type of permissions in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?  For example, are you asking your user if for permission to send notifications?  In my case, applicationDidBecomeActive is not being called until after the user selects 'Don't Allow' or 'Allow'.  This is causing an issue for me as applicationDidBecomeActive was previously being called before the notifications permissions request.  I'm trying to find a solution.

Comment: @JustinDomnitz No, there is no user interaction throughout the whole app session.

Comment: I too have seen this, there is a huge delay in calling applicationDidBecomeActive

Comment: For me too, huge delay

Comment: I am seeing a delay which prevents proper configuration for my application in the startup phase.   I have even suspended access to the item which needed configuration on launch, and now my initial storyboard simply doesn't load.  All started with Xcode 9 / 9.1 builds...